# Trouble starting postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql

I just got a copy of a VM running SLES10 in which I have Postgresql. I try to start it using the command "postgresql start" but it returns an error message: "could not start postmaster". On the old machine it works fine. The only things I did since copying the machine was to change its IP Address and name, install VMWare Tools and delete the postgresql logs directory /.../postgres/pg_log (I recreated it afterwards). I tried restarting the machine but I still get the error. What can I do to determine the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to determine the cause of the problem?

Check out the Postgres and system log files

My bet is that there is some problem with accessing the data directory e.g. the account running the postmaster does not have read/write access to that directory.

**Edit**
You can try to start Postgres "manually" (as opposed to the system provided scripts) by running:

```
pg_ctl -D /path/to/data/dir start
```

then you might be able to see error messages on the console. Make sure you are running this as the postgres user

Comment: do you mean the log files found in the pg_log folder that I just deleted? I checked and nothing was written there. Should I check somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I was referring to those. So nothing is written there even after you tried another restart? There must be *something* in the logs

Comment: no, nothing is written. could it be that it tries to write in the old, deleted folder even if the new one has exactly the same name and path?

Comment: The quickest way to see errors is to use pg_ctl to startup the database instead of the shell script. Then you might see any errors that are written to the console.

Comment: Did you make sure that the "new" pg_log has the proper security settings applied? Does the postgres account have read/write privileges there?

Comment: I tried to run "pg_ctl start" on both the original VM and on the copied one, and on both of them got the same results: if I run it as root it says "pg_ctl: cannot be run as root" and if I run it as an unpriviledged user I get: "pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment PGDATA unset"

Comment: See my example. You **have** to specify the data directory using the -D switch (and make sure you use the *postgres* user!)

Comment: I did what you said and got the error message "pg_ctl: could not read file /var/lib/pgsql/data/postmaster.opts". I checked the "data" folder and it was empty.

Comment: Well, without data directory you cannot start the server. You need to run initdb before that.

Comment: I checked on the original VM and the data folder (/var/lib/pgsql/data - hope I am looking in the right place) is also empty. However, here the command "postgresql restart" works fine. If I try to the pg_ctl command as you said I get the "could not read file" error message.

Comment: Then you need to check where the data directory is. This is probably defined somewhere in the configuration for the system service.

Comment: Still trying to find where the data directory is... The line where the data_directory is defined in postgresql.conf is commented. Will keep you updated!

Comment: This must be in the **system** configuration where pg_ctl is called. Most probably in the shell script named "postgresql" that you are running

Comment: Usually the pg_log directory is created within $PGDATA. Did you check that?

Comment: Apparently there is no PGDATA otherwise he wouldn't have got the error message *pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment PGDATA unset*

Comment: I checked in the postgresql script and the data directory is /var/lib/pgsql/data, which is empty. I don't know how this even works, but I've had enough. I am copying the VM again and hoping it will work this time.